# Android AlarmManager is not calling PendingIntent when app is in background

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In our app, we have functionality where user will get a reminder notification one day before the appointment at specific time. We set the date and time using calendar and in pending intent we give call to service. We have used alarm manager to trigger the pending intent at specific time. Service class contains notification builder code

private void setAlarm(Long dateInMillies, String testGroup, int i) {

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().
            getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Log.d("TAG", "setAlarm: Called ");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateInMillies);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    int scheduleNumber = i + 1;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
    intent.putExtra("event", testGroup);
    intent.putExtra("scheduleNumber", scheduleNumber);
    intent.putExtra("date", dateInMillies);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.
            getService(getApplicationContext(),
                    scheduleNumber,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    if (am != null) {
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Log.d("DateTime", "setAlarm: Time in milis "+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the manifest declaraion of `NotifyService`. Also, how do you know the `Service` isn't getting started by AlarmManager?

Comment: I kept the app in background and added one toast message in onStartCommand(), which didn't come up. In my manifest file I have added NotifyService.class as  <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.Gridsensehealth.kimstxPatient.schedule.NotifyService"
            />

Comment: Toast is unreliable as a debug method. Add logging (logcat) or set breakpoints.

Comment: I have added log statements also in the NotifyService.class

Comment: What device have you tested this on? Also, you might want to try having the AlarmManager send a broadcast `Intent` instead of starting a `Service`. Add logging and see if that works.